# DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'http://localhost:4200/BlinkCardWasmSDK.js' failed to load

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular11, domexception

I am trying to get [this](https://github.com/blinkcard/blinkcard-in-browser#installation) credit card reader to work on my angular application. I followed all the steps in the read me and got a license key as well but for some reason I am getting the following error

```
Error during the initialization of the SDK! DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'http://localhost:4200/BlinkCardWasmSDK.js' failed to load.
```

in my component I have the following method implemented from the instructions:

```
 scanCard() {
    if ( BlinkCardSDK.isBrowserSupported() ) {
      const loadSettings = new BlinkCardSDK.WasmSDKLoadSettings( 'sRwAAAYJbG9jYA==' );

      BlinkCardSDK.loadWasmModule( loadSettings ).then
      (
        ( wasmSDK: BlinkCardSDK.WasmSDK ) => {
          // The SDK was initialized successfully, save the wasmSDK for future use
          BlinkCardSDK.createBlinkCardRecognizer( wasmSDK ).then(recognizer => {
            BlinkCardSDK.createRecognizerRunner( wasmSDK, [ recognizer ], true ).then(recognizerRunner => {
              const cameraFeed = document.getElementById( 'camera-feed' ) as HTMLVideoElement;
              BlinkIDSDK.VideoRecognizer.createVideoRecognizerFromCameraStream(cameraFeed, recognizerRunner)
                .then(videoRecognizer => {
                  videoRecognizer.recognize().then(processResult => {
                    if ( processResult !== BlinkIDSDK.RecognizerResultState.Empty ) {
                     recognizer.getResult().then(recognitionResult => {
                       console.log( recognitionResult );

                     });
                    } else {
                      console.log( 'Recognition was not successful!' );
                    }
                    console.log(processResult);
                  });

              });
            });

          });
        },
        ( error: any ) => {
          // Error happened during the initialization of the SDK
          console.log( 'Error during the initialization of the SDK!', error );
        });
    } else {
      console.log( 'This browser is not supported by the SDK!' );
    }
  }
```

in the html I have:

```
<body>
<div id="screen-initial">
  <h1 id="msg">Loading...</h1>
  <progress id="load-progress" value="0" max="100"></progress>
</div>

<div id="screen-start" class="hidden">
  <a href="#" id="start-scan">Start scan</a>
</div>

<div id="screen-scanning" class="hidden">
  <video id="camera-feed" playsinline></video>
  <!-- Recognition events will be drawn here. -->
  <canvas id="camera-feedback"></canvas>
  <p id="camera-guides">Point the camera towards Payment cards.</p>
</div>
</body>
```

I have added the BlinkCardWasmSDK.js in the /src/assets/BlinkCardWasmSDK.js but it still gives me the error. Am I missing a reference or something? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is BlinkID cannot find the resources it requires. You need to point it to where the resources are in your angular.json configurations file ([Angular workspace configuration docs](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config)) in the architect, build, options, and finally assets array like so.

```
          "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/@microblink/blinkid-in-browser-sdk/resources",
                "output": "/"
              }
            ]
```

You don't need to move the BlinkID resources to your assets but to instead point to where it live in the node_modules. Let me know if this has helped.